# unity5 C#の場合のオブジェクトの移動について

Tags: c#

unity5 C#の場合のオブジェクトの移動について

2Dで横スクロールのゲームを作っているのですが、オブジェクト（敵）を右から左へウェーブ（波）のような軌道をしながら移動させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

CSの例など、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11162736391 マルチポスト

Comment: マルチポスト先にある画像を質問に掲載して良いでしょうか。[画像](https://iwiz-chie.c.yimg.jp/im_siggzPPeGC6Dt54qxsvQTpBPXQ---x320-y320-exp5m-n1/d/iwiz-chie/que-11162736391)

Comment: はい、大丈夫です。よろしくお願いします。